Validate a function call of already validated Pydatnic objects with validate_call
I want to check with pydantic v2, whether my function gets the correct input parameter at runtime.
As a guard/contract substitute.
def get_total_amount(
    areas: List[Area])

The Class is
class Area(BaseModel):
    """Area model."""

    AreaID: str
    slope: confloat(ge=0, le=90)
    orientiation: confloat(ge=-180, le=180)
    power: confloat(ge=0)

Data in _config have already been validated and _config.area as first parameter is of type List[Area].
get_total_production(
        _config.area)

For this code, I get the errors for all List elements like this:
0.0
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of Area[type=model_type, input_value=Area(AreaID='1ost'...on=100.0, power=2.43), input_type=Area]

This confuses me a lot: because it reads, it should be of the type it already is (see input_type). Instance attributes should not cause this error, because they already have been validated.
Why do I still get this error?

Could you provide the example of _config.area and the code for get_total_production?

@VictorEgiazarian I tried to create a minimal example, but that worked. Tried around for two hours. It did work, when the function was in the same module, but not when it was in the original import. I removed all imports in the calling module, and added them anew. I guess only the order of the import changed, but that helped.

Great, happy to hear!
